# Facebook Like Button in Jetpack

Tags: facebook, plugin-jetpack

I'd like to have a Facebook Like Button (not a Facebook share, which is available) through Jetpack. There is a "Add a new service" and I've tried various parts of code from all over but always gets an "An error occurred creating your new sharing service - please check you gave valid details."

Anyone knows howe to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to Settings > Sharing in your dashboard
2. Sroll down until the "Button Style" option.
3. Choose "Official Buttons".

The Facebook Share button has now changed into a Facebook Like Button. Save your changes, and you'll be good to go!

If you want to add a Facebook Share button next to the Like button, you can use the "Add a new service" option:

- In "Service Name", type in "Facebook"
- In Sharing URL, enter `http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=%post_full_url%`
- In Icon URL, enter a link to the Facebook icon of your choice.

And save changes.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, this "Button Style" -change, doesn't it change the facebook service completely? I mean "share" and "like" are not the same.

Comment: It does indeed completely change the service. The "Official Button" is the official Like button, while the "Icon + Text", "Icon", and "Text" button types are share buttons.

Comment: Room for UX improvement. They should be two different services. Also you might want to use them both at the same time.

Comment: If you want to use both at the same time, you can follow the instructions I posted above.

Comment: Perhaps this should be a separate question: If I would like the icons to be without text or count, I could just choose some of the alternatives in "Button Style". But this doesn't work for Facebook since this changes it's function from "Like" to Share. So how do I create a new Facebook like button in "Add new service" with or without text/count?

Comment: That's won't be possible. The Facebook Like button cannot be added via the "Add new service".

Since you want to implement a custom Facebook Like button on your site, it might be easier to create your own button by following the instructions here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Ok. I think this behaviour is a little odd and inflexible. There are other FB plugins having this functionality but since I already use Jetpack it would be nice if this could work. Is it worth suggesting on Trac?